# WebLogic 12.2 - кнопки Start и Stop на форме Deployments

Tags: oracle, развертывание, weblogic

Доброго дня профам от ламера! Сижу на Oracle WebLogic 12.2.1.3.0.
У кого-нибудь возникала на этой версии следующая ситуация: на форме Deployments есть кнопки деплоя модулей (Insert, Update и Delete), но **внезапно** не оказалось кнопок Start и Stop, которые есть на Oracle WebLogic 12.1.3.0.0.
Очень неудобно перезапускать модули через удаление, знаете ли. :)
Кто-нибудь в курсе, где находится настройка, которая "включает" эти кнопки? Или теперь такой возможности нет?

Answer (score 0):

Тут внезапно оказалось, что кнопки ушли с вкладки Configuration и остались только на вкладке Control. Очень "удобно", очень "комфортно".